# NetSuite Integration Through Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, netsuite

I am doing `NetSuite` Integration for my product in ASP.NET.
I have created a Custom List in `NetSuite` account and I want to add values to this list through ASP.NETcode.

Please someone can help me with the sample code ?

Comment: I would suggest adding some of your existing code.  That would help others see where you are needing assistance at, specifically.

Comment: I have no idea how to add new values to the NetSuite custom list.

Answer (score 1):

The easy fix is to just convert the custom list to a custom record. There is a checkbox for that on the custom list editor screen. Then you can add values as you normally would for a custom record. Totally supported and logical to do if the list elements vary.

Comment: Thanks bknights...but the checkbox is disabled in my case

Comment: You'll need more permissions then. Or ask an administrator to convert the list to a record

Answer (score 0):

This URL will show you how to add values to a custom list, manually.  https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10069/kw/create%20custom%20list.

According to this page (https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10242/kw/suitescript%20update%20custom%20list), SuiteScript does not allow custom lists to be edited.  I have, previously, found ways around what they say can't be done.  Though, that is only advisable if you want to keep updating the code to make sure they don't break it with updates... :)

Comment: https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10242/kw/suitescript%20update%20custom%20list not working

Comment: Works for me.  You have to log in.  Try logging into your NetSuite account, and going to support > Go To SuiteAnswers.  Then click that link.  At that point, you will already be in the SuiteAnswers site, so you should not have to log in again.